# Utility of an alien-psych and human-psych tags?

Tags: discussion

JDługosz just asked an interesting [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20565/what-would-be-the-mythology-of-an-aquatic-species) about the interaction between aquatic alien mythology and aquatic alien psychology.  The question is a good one but it makes me wonder if an alien-psych tag might be useful to help identify these kinds of questions.  And if an alien-psych tag is useful, perhaps a human-psych tag would be useful too?

Comment: Psych is for psychology ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We already have tags for [psychology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology), [alien](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien) and [humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humans).

The stats on these are currently:

- 38 questions tagged psychology
- 76 questions tagged alien
- 102 questions tagged humans

but **only two** questions are tagged *both* [psychology and alien](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology+alien). All of *four* are tagged [psychology and humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology+humans).

The question you cite as an example isn't even tagged psychology; it's tagged alien, religion, underwater.

I think this shows that there is not a great need at present for a tag *specifically* about *alien psychology*.

[Any user with sufficient reputation can create new tags](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), and nobody (not even us diamond moderators) has a veto on them (short of blacklisting, but that's not what we'd be doing here; blacklisting tags is primarily for tags that used to be considered acceptable but now aren't, but keeps coming back), but I think this site is mature enough by now that new tags should fill a real need in terms of categorizing questions.

If we had tons of questions tagged "alien psychology" then this might very well have been different, but as it stands, I don't see any real need that would be fulfilled by such a tag.

Hence, my stance at this time is to recommend **not** creating such a (highly specific) tag.